# State Pattern with Conditional State Change

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-pattern

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around one aspect of the State pattern. I understand the basic examples provided on wikipedia, etc. but what if I your `StateContext` class is making conditional state changes on say a timer distinct to each state?

So for example, say our states are `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. And I want to change states based on a state-based timer. For example remain in A for 5 seconds, B for 7 seconds, C for 3 seconds, and D for 10 seconds.

Who should manage that duration? Should each state be aware of its duration? In that case, I feel icky copying and pasting the `_duration` attribute to each state and think maybe my `State` interface should be an abstract base class with that attribute.

Or should the `StateContext` manage the durations? In which case I feel icky doing `IsInstanceOf` checks on my `_state`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `StateContext` nor `State` are responsible for managing the state changes, it's something managed from outside this pattern. You should probably have a `setState(...)` method or another method to change the current `State` instance in your `StateContext` class.

Comment: Ok fair enough. So then it would be acceptable for some external StateController class to know and make decisions based on the state in StateContext?

Comment: Sorry for the exhaustiveness answer. You said you had a look to the Wikipedia example, right? Take the drawing program example, then. It's the UI to be responsible for the state change in the `StateContext`. Whenever you click on the pen tool or the selection tool, the `State` instance in the `StateContext` changes. Now do you see it? :)